# Need help for Css issues

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I have Repeater Control as shown below.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCategory" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
       <h2 class="art-logo-text" style="margin-bottom: 5px; color: #008752!important;font-size:16pt;">
            Course Categories</h2>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="2px" style="margin-left:0px">
            <tr>
                <td>
                   <div  id="divleft">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCategory" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryDescription")%>'
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CourseLibraryCategoryID") %>' OnClick="lnkCategory_Click"
                            CssClass="courseLink">
                        </asp:LinkButton>

                    </div>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I want to do that when my mouse over on linkbutton The background of div 'divleft' background should be green and mouse out the background color should remove means white....and when i click on Linkbutton at that time at that perticular div background should be green means it should be selected....what is the best way to do this plz help me....

Comment: Did you try :hover and :selected?

Comment: No i havent try it but this is the repeater control so i am afraid that is it working hover and selected.....i am not sure about this...can u plz show me the idea .....

Comment: i had try   #divleft:hover
       {
           background-color:Green;
       }
       #divleft:selected
       {
           background-color:Green;
       }         In this one hover is working fine but selected css is not working

Comment: `:selected` or `:active` wont work; you need to highlight the _container_ div, not the link itself

Comment: Use `:active` for when mouse has clicked.

Comment: you linkbutton will cause a postback, and so any javascript modification wont persist as the page will reload...

Comment: Think I'm confused over the question now. Your question as stated implies all links will have a green background, which will go white on mouseover, and green again when clicked. Are you instead wanting *one* green background, to indicate which link is the current page?

Comment: I wouldn't use an id="divleft" in a repeater, I would change it to class="divleft"  id tends to be used as a unique identifier, but since it's in a repeater I'd expect you'll have many of them.

Comment: mshsayem:can You please give me the exact solution for this?

Comment: ok i have remove id and put class in place of id but still not working the selected css....

Comment: What does the `lnkCategory_Click` method do (on the server side)? Are you using update-panels?

Comment: i have code for lnkCategory_Click when i click on any Category some code is going to execute.....

Comment: If that linkbutton's purpose is just to add some highlighting color, you should use a simple html link..

Comment: No in code behind of lnkCategory_click there is some code that needs to be executed.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these styles:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .courseLink
    {
        display:block;
        height:100%;
        width:100%;
        background-color:Green;
    }
    .courseLink:hover
    {
        background:none;
    }
    .courseLink:active
    {
        background-color:Green;
    }
</style>
```

Since you said you wanted it to display the background in the parent div, I've added Height and Width properties

Comment: Hello can you please check ? .courseLink:selected css is not working.............

Comment: @KartikPatel Is the `:active` styling not accomplishing what you are asking?  It's working in Chrome and IE9.

Comment: Not working in any browser...i think it may be due to after click on linkbutton postback occurs....

Comment: @KartikPatel Yes, that's correct, and then it's green again. Unless your mouse is over the link (which it probably will be), in which case it's white, as requested. You are looking for a solution that ignores the `:hover` class if mouse just happens to be in that location on a postback?

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
#divleft:hover, .selected
{
   background-color:green;
}
```

For linkbutton, add this javascript(jQuery):

```
$('#<%# lnkCategory.ClientID %>').click(function(){
   // First remove all other rows which was selected before 
   // and you dont want those to remain selected if another 
   // row is selected. Otherwise, remove the following line
   $("#divleft").removeClass("selected");
   $(this).closest('div').addClass("selected");
   return false;
});
```

[This will work if your actual mark-up is just as you showed]

**EDIT:**
Here is the updated solution(postback remedy):

ASPX (Add a scriptmanager, add `OnClientClick` event on linkbutton, add `OnItemCreated` event on repeater, include jquery):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function highlight(lb) {
            $(".divleft").removeClass("selected");
            $(lb).closest('div').addClass('selected');
        }    
</script>


 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptCategory" runat="server" OnItemCreated="rptCategory_ItemCreated">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <h2 class="art-logo-text" style="margin-bottom: 5px; color: #008752!important; font-size: 16pt;">
                Course Categories</h2>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table cellpadding="2px" cellspacing="2px" style="margin-left: 0px">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="divleft">
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkCategory" ClientIDMode="Predictable" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CategoryDescription")%>'
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CourseLibraryCategoryID") %>' OnClientClick="highlight(this)"
                                OnClick="lnkCategory_Click" CssClass="courseLink">
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate>
        </FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

On the server-side add this method:

```
 protected void rptCategory_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
 {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(e.Item.FindControl("lnkCategory"));
            }
  }
```

Hope it helps. (sorry for being late, I was gaming :p)

Comment: Did you notice whether your page causes postback after clicking?

Comment: yes it is postback.....thats why i need the solution for this.....